# how to set login expiry time in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I have implemeted spring security in springboot . now  i want login expiry time of 10 min so that after expiry the page will be redirected to a page
`
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

@Bean
AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/js/**","/webjars/**","/images/**","/css/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(loginSuccessHandler).permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll();
    
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
    .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/sessionExpired");
    /*http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/")
        .permitAll()*/
        
    /*.and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/checkLogin")
        .failureUrl("/login")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .permitAll()*/
    /*.and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        ;*/
        
    
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

For Springboot application you need to set property in application.property named `server.servlet.session.timeout=15m`. If time unit is not specified by default it takes seconds